# conditionalPanel in Shiny not working

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use conditionalPanel to display message when a file is being loaded. However, the panel is not disappearing once the condition is TRUE. I have created a reproducible code below:

server.R

```
library(shiny)

print("Loading start")
print(paste("1->",exists('FGram')))
FGram <- readRDS("data/UGram.rds")
print(paste("2->",exists('FGram')))
print("Loading end")

shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI( fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Side Panel")
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("Main Panel"),
      br(),
      textOutput("First Line of text.."),
      br(),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "exists('FGram')", HTML("PLEASE WAIT!!     <br>App is loading, may take a while....")),
      br(),
      h4("Last Line of text..")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: conditions are supposed to be in javascript, not R. If you open the developer panel in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+J), I bet you'll see an error in the console. You won't be able to get a conditional panel to check the R environment for the existence of a variable.

Comment: I use conditionalPanel() all the time in shiny dashboards with menu items where selecting a different menu removes the conditionalPanel. Not clear what would 'trigger' it to be removed in this specific case. You may need some server side processing as the UI won't be able to react on own.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew.  I saw this error in console : "Uncaught ReferenceError: exists is not defined" Any workaround to this?

Comment: @user3949008, But does that not defeat the purpose of conditionalPanel() if I have to handle it separately on server side. Any pointers is appreciated as I am new to this.

Comment: @PeterV, no. You can't call R code or inspect the R environment from the javascript environment, which is where the `condition` statement is execute. What you can do is use custom message handlers in Shiny to create a new environment variable.

Comment: .. or use reactive output. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditions supplied to `conditionalPanel` are executed in the javascript environment, not the R environment, and therefore cannot reference or inspect variables or functions in the R environment. A solution to your situation would be to use `uiOutput`, as in the example below.

```
myGlobalVar <- 1

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$condPanel <- renderUI({
        if (exists('myGlobalVar')) 
            HTML("PLEASE WAIT!!     <br>App is loading, may take a while....")
    })

}

ui <- fluidPage({
    uiOutput('condPanel')
})


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Matthew, thanks for the example. However, i want to display this when the object is not present. So I modified it to (!exist()). But that app does not reach this point till it has done loading the data. So, right now, I can only display a message that "the data has been loaded" after the object is created. But there is no way to let the user know that the data is being loaded...